# Codeigniter: can't get the value passed in uri segment

Tags: codeigniter

I am currently having an issue getting the value of a uri segment.

Here's the scenario.

when the user clicks this anchor:

```
<?php echo anchor("site/comment/$row->post_id", "Comment"); ?>
```

the link in the address bar of the browser becomes:

```
http://localhost/CI_TEST/index.php/site/comment/140838624
```

As you can see there really is a value on the third segment of the link.
Now, when I try to get that value in my query like this:

```
$comment_data = array(
        'post_id' => $this->uri->segment(3),
        'date_commented' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),            
        );
```

and send it on the database, the value that is saved is zero when supposedly, it should be 140838624.

Any ideas? What am I missing here?

Comment: check out if your table field is BIGINT

Comment: yep, tried that. still, same thing happens

Comment: What does $this->uri->segment_array() return? What happens if you echo $this->uri->segment(3)?

Comment: YEp, please write var_dump results.

Comment: when I

echo $this->uri->segment(3)

the value being passed is actually shown.

Comment: "and send it on the database" <-- We need to see the code that does that, and probably your table schema, as long as what you say is true - that `$this->uri->segment(3)` is showing the right value. What happens when you hardcode a value like `123`? Same problem? Needs more debugging results.

Comment: I agree, the code as written is correct. The error lies somewhere that we can't see. Please post more code as @WesleyMurch suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what are you getting in uri segment 2 and 4. Are you  even able to get any value from the uri? You can use die() and echo to debug it. Also did you include 'url' in helpers in autoload.